# cron job 2nd line doesn't execute

Tags: cron, cron-task

I have these 2 lines in cron tab.
The 1st command executes but the 2nd one doesn't. It just doesn't run. No traces in log. I have a new line (enter) at the end. I have restarted the cron service also. 
The path is correct, I can run it as shell command.
Not sure what's going on

```
01 4,8,13 * * 1-5 sudo java -jar /opt/collective/classifier/classifier-1.0.jar both
01 21 * * 0-5 sudo java -jar /opt/collective/ikwkrefresh/ikwk-refresh-1.0.jar
```

Comment: Try to check file permissions for the second!